# Change Week Numbers to number of weeks that have passed rather than week number of the year

Tags: r, datetime

I am trying to create a column in a dataset that will indicate what week the data in a row was collected. I have come partway to a solution using the following code:

```
df$Week <- as.integer(format(df$Date_time, "%V"))
df<- transform(df, Week = Week - min(Week) + 1)
```

This produces the column I want, however, it numbers the weeks by the week of the year, starting at 49, rather than just a cumulative number of weeks starting at 1. I'm attempting to just subtract the week by the minimum value in the "week" column and adding 1, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
    Target_length_across_beams Target_range_extent Ping_number         Target_class Target_orientation ...45        Date_time      Week
                       -9.9e+37            -9.9e+37           0 Unclassified targets           -9.9e+37    NA 2020-12-01 18:14:54   49
                       -9.9e+37            -9.9e+37           0 Unclassified targets           -9.9e+37    NA 2020-12-01 18:14:54   49
                       -9.9e+37            -9.9e+37           0 Unclassified targets           -9.9e+37    NA 2020-12-01 18:14:54   49
                       -9.9e+37            -9.9e+37           1 Unclassified targets           -9.9e+37    NA 2020-12-01 18:14:55   49
                       -9.9e+37            -9.9e+37           1 Unclassified targets           -9.9e+37    NA 2020-12-01 18:14:55   49
                       -9.9e+37            -9.9e+37           1 Unclassified targets           -9.9e+37    NA 2020-12-01 18:14:55   49
```

What I want is for the "49" in the week column to be changed to "1" and for that value to increase by 1 for each consecutive week.

Answer (score 1):

Not very sure if this is what you want:

```r
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(1)
df1 <- data.frame(date = ymd("2020-01-01") + runif(4, 0, 365)) %>%
  arrange(date)
df1 %>%
  mutate(week = week(date),
         week_xx = week - min(week) + 1
  )
#>         date week week_xx
#> 1 2020-04-06   14       1
#> 2 2020-05-15   20       7
#> 3 2020-07-28   30      17
#> 4 2020-11-27   48      35
```